# boost asio tcp::socket::read_some(const MutableBufferSequence & buffers, boost::system::error_code & ec) is unable to receive message and blocks

Tags: boost, tcp, blocking, asio

I am using boost 1.66.0. I call this function to receive messages from a remote client. Initially it works. However, after idling for at most 6 hours, it cannot receive message from the client, or unblock with error. It simply hangs, even when the client disconnects.

Any ideas about the cause of this issue? Thanks!

I tried to set keep_alive option on the acceptor but it did not make a difference. Maybe I should set this option on the socket.

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
tcp::socket socket_;
tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), port);
uint8_t buf[MAX_LEN];
acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
acceptor_.set_option(option);
acceptor_.bind(endpoint);``
acceptor_.set_option(socket_base::keep_alive(true));
while(true)
{
    acceptor_.accept(socket_);
    while(true)
    {
        boost::system::error_code error;
        int nRead = socket_.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, MAX_LEN), error);
        if(error)
        {
            break;
        }
        //... process received message
    }
}
```

The code blocks at socket_.read_some() line.

Question: why is there such a blocking? The keepalive setting seems to be able to unblock it after a long period of time (> 2 hours).

Comment: No code, no comment